# How do I query a remote oracle database from an HTML web application?

Tags: java, javascript, database, oracle, html

I'm designing a web application that's HTML 5. I need to query a remote oracle database (I have all of the credentials) with a specific query, then display the results in the web page. What is the best way to accomplish this? I have a java application that queries my database and displays information for me (non-parsed as of now). Is it possible to grab the information from this java application using JavaScript and display it through the HTML? I have looked for an solution for this but I'm still not clear. I'd like to avoid PHP as it seems that it requires installation on the database server. From an architecture stand-point, I'm just not sure how I should go about this. Could you walk me through the steps of the common way of doing this? I'll do all of the research. This is what I was thinking so far just so I'm being a little more clear in terms of the overall flow of the data:

HTML 5 <-> JavaScript <-> Java <-> Oracle Database

Is this even possible?

Kenneth

Comment: You need a server side language to access the data.  Something like ASP.net, PHP, JSP, etc.

Comment: ASP , Ruby on Rails, PHP. Last thing you want to do is put sql in your web page. Might has well call your page "about to be hacked" as do that.

Comment: So you're saying HTML 5 <-> ASP <-> Ruby on Rails <-> PHP <-> Database? I've never done anything like this so that's why I'm asking for help. Sounds like I need something on the server, and there's no choice. If that's the case, what would the PHP route be? Thanks guys.

Comment: HTML 5 + JavaScript <-> Java <-> Oracle Database : this is possible!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already developed Java code to work with the database, you can use the same application logic and create a JSP page. JSP is quiet simple to learn if you already know HTML and Java.

There's a short tutorial here - [JSP Quick Guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_quick_guide.htm) (tutorialspoint.com)

Basically a JSP page is much like a HTML page but you can insert Java code in it. The Java code gets executed in the server and the JSP turns into a pure HTML page when it comes to the client.

Comment: Is JSP compatible with mobile browsers? What are my limitations there? The Web application I'm developing is targeted for mobile devices. Also, does JSP require any additional installation?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that this application is specifically targeted for mobile. I need to know if this places any additional constraints. Our target platform is iOS. Is JSP still valid for these purposes?

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML5 + CSS + JavaScript code only needs to send database requests to the server (and renders it itself), easy ways to communicate with the Oracle database are

- Servlets
- JAX-RS (RESTful) web services

on a Java EE (Web Profile) application server.

In both cases you could reuse existing Java / JDBC database access code and simply serialize the data as JSON, which can be used in your JavaScript code.